# Random Forest different results for same observation

Tags: r, random-forest

Hi I am fairly new to Random Forest estimation, but I could not find a questions similiar to mine. I was surprised that the predictions are different using the same predictors. I would have expected the same. I understand, that the model would be different with each estimation, but getting different predictions for the same predictors?

```
library(randomForest)
set.seed(100)
df<-mtcars
rt.est<-randomForest(mpg ~ ., 
                     data = df,
                     ntree=1000)
predict(rt.est)
df.double<-rbind(df,df[32,])
rt.est<-randomForest(mpg ~ ., 
                     data = df.double,
                    ntree=1000)
predict(rt.est)
```

The results for the last Observation on the Volvo142E are similiar but not the same. Why?

Comment: Once you have an answer to the question as stated, you shouldn't really change the substance of the question in a way that breaks the connection with the existing answers.  If you wan to ask another question as a fork of this, just start a new thread. You can link back for context, if you want.

Comment: I did not alter the questions substantially. It was always about having a different prediction for the same predictors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you supply the argument `newdata` the discrepancy disappears: `predict(rt.est, newdata=df)` gives

```
Volvo 142E 
22.15557 

Volvo 142E1 
22.15557
```

When you do not supply `newdata`, it's probably reporting the out-of-bag results, but I haven't found an explicit clarification of this in the documentation. Samples that are "in-bag" were included in a tree during training as a result of the bootstrap re-sampling procedure; out-of-bag samples were omitted.

We can verify that this is out-of-bag data by calling `rt.est$predicted` which reports the out-of-bag predictions. The results match `predict(rt.est)`.

```
Volvo 142E 
22.83609 

Volvo 142E1 
22.85975
```

One way to think of `predict.randomForest` is that it's a shortcut to the out-of-bag predictions *unless* you supply `newdata`.

---

OP originally asked about 2 different ensembles of random forests. This portion of the answer addresses why 2 random forest ensembles might make different predictions on the same data.

## The trees are different.

First, `randomForest` is a random procedure: both the samples chosen for each tree are different (bootstrap resampling), and the features chosen at each split are chosen at random (randomized feature subspaces). Without fixing the random seed, we would expect two `randomForest` runs to produce different results with high probability for the same reason that flipping a fair coin 1000 times will plausibly result in a different sequence of heads and tails. (You have fixed the seed, however the two instances of `randomForest` will still be different because the **random state is altered** after the first `randomForest` is produced.)

Second, The data used to train the models is different. It appears that you've added an additional row. Different data makes for a different model, which makes for a different prediction.  When `randomForest` conducts its bootstrapping, the probability that `df[32,]` is in-bag for that tree is larger than for each non-duplicated sample. This change to the data will also change the trees, because choices about where to make splits will be influenced by the increased prominence of this sample.

## Different trees make different predictions.

Having the same feature values is only half the battle. The other half is how the trees are constructed.

As an example, suppose I have 3 trees constructed with the random forest procedure, each with 1 split.

1. This tree has a bootstrap resample and randomly samples `cyl`, `disp` and `hp`. It picks splitting on `cyl` at 5 as the best split.
2. This tree has a bootstrap resample and randomly samples `cyl`, `disp` and `hp`. It picks splitting on `cyl` at 7 as the best split.
3. This tree has a bootstrap resample and randomly samples `wt`, `disp` and `hp`. It picks splitting on `hp` at 123 as the best split.

Clearly there will be different predictions whenever the splits change the decision of a sample. A sample with `cyl` 6 might go "right" for  tree 1, but "left" for tree 2. Feature `hp` doesn't have a one-to-one relationship to `cyl`, so a split on `hp` won't generally match splits on `cyl`.

Comment: That i understand. I added one Observation ran the model again and would have expected the same result for the Observation #32 because it has the same predictors.

Comment: If you have two completely different decision trees, are they guaranteed to make the same predictions?

Comment: I edited my Code to make it clearer what confuses me. I do understand that each run of the randomforest command yields a different model if I do not set a seed, but why is the prediction for my last two observations different?

So you are saying that the prediction can slighly deviate at the cutoff Point? But this would be more likely for categorical predictors then?

Comment: Oh thats surprising to me. So ist a using kind of a mixed random drawn sample to get the predictions for the model? Is this not contradicting your original answer then???

Comment: No, that's absolutely not what it's doing. Please read the explanation in my answer. The behavior of the function changes depending on what arguments you do or do not give to it. Your original question asked about a comparison between 2 random forest ensembles. Your revised question asks about how the function `predict` works.

Comment: No it never did, it was always about the difference of having the same Observation twice. I only included the estimation with the original data set for Demonstration, but apparently that was confusing...

Comment: anyhow, now ist clear...

Comment: Just to clarify one last time for me. I have worked with my real data set and while the predicitions for identical observations are now much closer together they are not always equal. THis is then due to the random Splitting that you mention in the second half of your answer?

Comment: It could be, but it's not possible to answer without knowing the commands you're running. You can ask a new question.

Comment: basically the same as up there just with a bigger and more complex data set. More categorical variables etc.. The delta between the pedictions of identical observations has decresed a lot using the `newdata=data` Option in `predict`

Comment: "basically the same" suggests to me that the code is not identical. Since you're trying to pin down the cause of a small discrepancy, small differences in the code could be the cause. You should ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem using the package randomForest for a binary classification. In my case, executing predict() on the same rf and the same validation set consisting of a single record I got different predictions, sometimes 0 and sometimes 1.

I discovered that such issue is present when both output classes have the same probability, predict(..., type="response") returns sometimes 0 and sometimes 1. So, I guess, it is a bug related to the precision of the computation.

I solved the issue by calling predict(..., type="prob") and then computing the prediction myself.

Comment: I think that is what the accepted answer discusses at the end. But thanks anyway