# Fitted RF: difference between the probabilities in $votes and predict (type="prob")

Tags: r, random-forest, prediction

Say we have a data frame `df` where `diagnosis` is the first column. There are only 2 possible values for `diagnosis`: C and N.

We fit a random forest:

```
rf <- randomForest(diagnosis ~ ., data=df)
```

We then extract probabilities in two different ways:

```
probs1 = rf$votes
probs2 = predict(rf, df[,-1], type="prob" )
```

So if we now examine these extracted probabilities:

```
> head(probs1)
                     C          N
sample1220  0.52095808 0.47904192
sample1831  0.06698565 0.93301435
sample526   0.15286624 0.84713376
sample1225  0.30808081 0.69191919
sample523   0.03910615 0.96089385
sample644   0.97093023 0.02906977

> head(probs2)
                C     N
sample1220  0.174 0.826
sample1831  0.028 0.972
sample526   0.734 0.266
sample1225  0.726 0.274
sample523   0.014 0.986
sample644   0.990 0.010
```

Why are the probabilities in `probs2` (from the predict function) different from the ones in `probs1` (which are the proportions of votes) ?

I thought the probabilities **were** the proportions of votes, but clearly that's not the case. Could anybody please explain?

Comment: What discrepancy have you observed? Can you share examples of the discrepant predictions? There's not much to say with so little information. I suspect you're describing the same issue as here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/405234/random-forest-different-results-for-same-observation/405237#405237 If you can't share your data, you can use a publicly-available data set to share your findings.

Comment: I was confused by the terminology. You're talking about "merging" accounts, but I've only ever registered one account. When I originally posted my question, I clicked on the "post as guest" option, so there's an inconsistency in the terminology there. Thanks very much for your kind help.

Answer (score 2):

The observed behavior in the post is expected behavior, and essentially a duplicate of
[Random Forest different results for same observation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/405234/random-forest-different-results-for-same-observation/405237#405237)

The discrepancy you find is fully explained by understanding what the software is doing. Attribute `rf$votes` reports OOB results for the training data, while calling `predict(rf, newdata=something, ...)` (which is syntactically equivalent to `predict(rf,something, ...)`) reports predictions for the **whole** ensemble, without regard to in- or out-of-bag status. The two results would agree if you did not supply argument `newdata` in the call to predict, as in `predict(rf,type="prob")`.

From the documentation:

> `votes`
>   (classification only) a matrix with one row for each input data point and one column for each class, giving the fraction or number of (OOB) `votes' from the random forest.

Where as for the predict method we have

> `newdata` a data frame or matrix containing new data. (Note: If not given, the out-of-bag prediction in object is returned.)

So putting these two facts together, we can conclude that supplying the argument `newdata` is giving the random forest's predictions including **all** of the trees, while `votes` is only reporting OOB results. Obviously, these wouldn't agree in general, so that's why your results disagree.

Comment: Thank you very much Sycorax for your answer. Much appreciated. Can I please check if I understand what you're saying?
Are you saying that the probabilities are different because the probabilities that come from `predict` are computed using the votes from all the trees in the forest, whereas the probabilities in `$votes` are computed using only the votes of the trees who **never saw** the corresponding rows of the dataframe during training? Thanks!

Comment: The operation of `predict` changes depending on whether or not you supply `newdata` as an argument to the call. If you **don't** supply a `newdata` argument, you get OOB predictions from the training data. If you **do** supply `newdata`, then you get predictions from the whole ensemble. `rf$votes` reports OOB results for the training data. In any case, the software doesn't make any sort of comparison to determine if any provided data matches the original training data.

Comment: I saw that's what you explained in the other thread, and I don't fully understand it because I don't fully understand what "out of bag" means. I've been looking for a definition, but every time I look it up, I find stuff about "out of bag error", but I haven't been able to find a definition of what OOB itself means. Could you please give me a definition of OOB or point me to somewhere where I can read what exactly OOB means? Thanks very much.

Comment: Each tree in a random forest is grown using a bootstrap sample of the data. The data in the bootstrap is in bag. The data that is not in the bootstrap is out of bag.

Comment: so the probability in `$votes` for each row is computed only with the votes of the trees for which that row is out of bag?

Comment: You'll find the answer to that question if you re-read my answer.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I've read all your answers several times and I'm still not sure. Is the probability in `$votes` for each row computed only with the votes of the trees for which that row is out of bag?

Comment: `rf$votes` is OOB

Comment: I understand that, and you've very kindly explained what OOB is. But there are several ways that concept could be interpreted in the context of computing the votes. Is the probability in `$votes` for each row computed only with the votes of the trees for which that row is out of bag?